# awk find lines between range

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to use awk to get all lines between two words. My first word is a directory and my second is a sequence of four minus charaters like so: ----

Here is what I have tried:

```
awk '/\/ua\/Debug\/xeGenReport\/src\//,/----/ errorLog2
```

Sample input:

```
/ua/Debug/xeGenReport/src/
++++
16955:../main2.C:492:22: error: something
16959:../main2.C:577:21: error: something
16963:../report2.C:2630:22: error: something
----
/ua/Debug/xeGenReport/src/ // I don't want this line in the final output
----
More text here I don't want
```

Desired output:

```
/ua/Debug/xeGenReport/src/
++++
16955:../main2.C:492:22: error: something
16959:../main2.C:577:21: error: something
16963:../report2.C:2630:22: error: something
----
```

I have tried other permutations, all give me different errors.

Comment: What does "All lines between two words" means... lines aren't between words, words are in lines... I feel like I'm missing something here. Perhaps share some sample data and what you are trying to extract from it.

Comment: Post sample data

Comment: @Jotne added sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the /

Some like this (exclude start/stop):

```
awk '/----/{f=0} f; /\/ua\/Debug\/xeGenReport\/src/{f=1}' file
++++
16955:../main2.C:492:22: error: something
16959:../main2.C:577:21: error: something
16963:../report2.C:2630:22: error: something
```

Or like this (include start/stop): (use exit to not get more than needed)

```
awk '/\/ua\/Debug\/xeGenReport\/src/{f=1} f; /----/{exit}' file
/ua/Debug/xeGenReport/src/
++++
16955:../main2.C:492:22: error: something
16959:../main2.C:577:21: error: something
16963:../report2.C:2630:22: error: something
----
```

Edit:  This is from my personal archive :)

### * Print text between "START/END" not inclusive (replace {f=0} with {exit} to prevent repetision)

> **exclusive**
>   awk '/START/{f=1;next} /END/{f=0} f'
>   awk '/END/{f=0} f; /START/{f=1}'       #best
>   **inclusive**
>   awk '/START/{f=1} /END/{f=0;print} f'
>   awk '/START/{f=1} f; /END/{f=0}'
>   awk '/START/,/END/'
>   sed -n '/SRART/,/END/p'
>   Do not print between from START to END #inclusive
>   awk '/START/{f=1;next} !f; /END/{f=0}'
>   awk '/START/,/END/{next}1'
>   sed '/START/,/END/d'

Comment: FWIW `awk '$0=="----"{f=0} f; $0=="/ua/Debug/xeGenReport/src"{f=1}' file` would be more robust and IMHO clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a school of thought that range patterns should be avoided, but since Jotne already posted the flag-style version, I'll show this alternative, which follows more closely to your original attempt:

```
$ awk '/\/ua\/Debug\/xeGenReport\/src/,/----/ {print; if ($0 ~ /----/) exit}' file
/ua/Debug/xeGenReport/src/
++++
16955:../main2.C:492:22: error: something
16959:../main2.C:577:21: error: something
16963:../report2.C:2630:22: error: something
----
```

Comment: That demonstrates one of the problems with a range expression and why they should be avoided - you need to test for `/----/` twice to get the behavior you want unlike in the flag case where you just need to test each condition once.